# Waiting for a jQuery animation to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
if ($('#container').is(':visible'))
{
    $('#container').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        $('#' + id).toggle();
    });
}
else
{
    $('#' + id).toggle(0, function() {
        $('#container').slideToggle('fast');
    });
}
```

This code is contained within a much larger method which I will not post here. The method is responsible for toggling between the style and behaviour of a set of buttons, and in the above code, a container is displayed/hidden when a button is pressed. If a button is currently pressed down (hence a container is displayed) but the user clicks another button, the above method is called first on the currently pressed button to hide its container and then on the button that was just clicked to show *its* container.

The problem is that the animation for the currently pressed button doesn't finish (or doesn't even seem to start as I observed whilst debugging) before the method is executed for the button just pressed.

Does anyone know how to make the code wait for the animation queue to empty before returning from this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with the `Deferred` / `promise` object which is provided by jQuery for animated elements (alongside other things, like XHR requests).

That means, you can always hook into a promise like so

```
function foo() {
    return $('#someElement').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    }).promise();
}
```

and then call it like

```
foo().done(function() {
    alert('animation finished');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dCVnG/

Comment: Is it possible on the method call to write: var promise = foo().promise(); and then on the second call to the method write: promise.done(function() { }); ?

Comment: I don't think I understand that, please elaborate.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think it will work. I'll read into these two objects and give it a shot later.

Comment: In my situation I found a better solution, but I will give you the answer since yours was the only one :)